# Reviewboard 1.6.3 manage.py test run 0 test in 0.000s

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, review-board

I am having a problem running test cases in reviewboard 1.6.3
The structure is goes like this

```
/reviewboard
  __init__.py
  settings.py
  settings_local.py
  manage.py
  /reviews
  __init__.py
  models.py
  tests.py
```

I have tried running:
python manage.py test

but it keeps giving me

Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?
I just want to run the tests.py

Code base is from this repository:
https://github.com/reviewboard/reviewboard/tree/release-1.6.x

Comment: Have you tried the verbose option? Try `python manage.py test -v`

Comment: Do you have any tests? If there are tests, your test runner is not finding them.